# QNX 7.1 command "on -A allow,root -d test.sh" returns error status 10 (No child processes)

Tags: qnx, blackberry-qnx

In the Qnx 7.1 there is startup script which is executed by command like:

```
on -T somepolicy_t -A allow,root -d /usr/sbin/test_startup.sh
```

This command return error status 10 which, I assume from the errno documentation, is "No child processes"
From what I tested, it seems that it doesn't matter what is in the test_startup.sh.
Currently I modified this script to do only **echo "Marker 1"** and the issue is still present.

When I remove one of the argument -A or -d the issue disappears (command returns 0)

I'm not sure if this is relevant but this secpol policy is currently setup as unrestricted and it allows for everything (based on the pidin -f aN_k).

I'm also not sure why there are both -T and -A, from what I understand they are responsible for the same thing, but I'm hesitant to remove -A as I would have quite big problem to confirm that everything works correctly.

**Would you have any suggestion what can cause the "on" command to returns 10 instead of 0 in such case?**